# how can I custom error message in AOP around annotations?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-aop, custom-errors

I want to custom error message in AOP around annotations.
I used to use @RestControllerAdvice before but It didn't work in AOP around method.
it outputs default error message.

I tried to input message in try ~ catch I know it's weird like //// 1 or //// 2

But I can't get to the point :(

#### TransactionAspect class

```java
    @Around("execution(* com.bono.server.controller..*(..))")
    @Transactional
    public Object caculatePerformanceTime(ProceedingJoinPoint proceedingJoinPoint) {
        Object result = null;
        try {
            result = proceedingJoinPoint.proceed();
        } catch (CustomeException e) { ////// 1
            throw new ErrorMessage(CustomError.HTTP_400_MISTYPE);
        }
        catch (Throwable throwable) { /////// 2
            return new ErrorMessage(CustomError.HTTP_400_MISTYPE);
        }
        return result;
    }
```

#### ErrorMessage class

```java
@Getter
@Setter
public class ErrorMessage {

    private int errorCode;
    private String errorMessage;

    public ErrorMessage(CustomError customError) {
        this.errorCode = customError.errorCode();
        this.errorMessage = customError.errorMessage();
    }
}
```

#### GroupExceptionAdvice class

```java
@RestControllerAdvice
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class GroupExceptionAdvice extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

    //// 1
    @ExceptionHandler(value = CustomeException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<CustomErrorResponse> customhandleNotSatisfied(Exception ex, WebRequest request) {
        CustomErrorResponse error = new CustomErrorResponse();
        error.setTimestamp(LocalDateTime.now());
        error.setError(ex.getMessage());
        error.setStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND.value());

        return new ResponseEntity<>(error, HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }

    //// 2
    @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
    @ExceptionHandler(value = CustomException.class)
    public ErrorMessage handlerUnResolvedAddressException(MisTypingException e) {
        return new ErrorMessage(CustomError.HTTP_400_MISTYPE);
    }
}
```

```
{
    "timestamp": "2019-08-12T01:14:16.467+0000",
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "message": "class com.bono.server.config.exception.ErrorMessage cannot be cast to class org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity (com.bono.server.config.exception.ErrorMessage and org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity are in unnamed module of loader 'app')",
    "path": "/bono/api/alarm"
}
```

I want to show like this

```
{
    "code" : 102,
    "message" : "got it !"
}
```

Comment: Your `ErrorMessage` class does not extend any exception or throwable class, so how can you throw it?

Comment: @kriegaex Thank for you answer 
can you tell me some key words about this issue? I don't want to have the correct answer directly

Comment: I just mean that in your sample class I expected to see something like `public class ErrorMessage extends Exception` for a checked exception or `public class ErrorMessage extends RuntimeException` for a non-checked exception. But your class definition does not extend anything, i.e. implicitly it directly extends `Object`.

Comment: thank you for your reply
I think the key is like this Around("execution(* com.bono.server.controller..*(..))")
my RestControllerAdvice class is located 'com.bono.server.config.aop.RestControllerAdvice'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Converting my previous comments into an answer because the OP said that they solved his problem.*

Your `ErrorMessage` class does not extend any `Exception` or `Throwable`, so how can you throw it? The code should not even compile and yield a compile error like:

```
No exception of type ErrorMessage can be thrown;
an exception type must be a subclass of Throwable
```

I.e. in your sample class I you ought to write something like

```java
public class ErrorMessage extends Exception {
  // (...)
}
```

for a checked exception or

```java
public class ErrorMessage extends RuntimeException {
  // (...)
}
```

for a non-checked exception. But your class definition does not extend anything, i.e. implicitly it directly extends `Object`.